# Multiple methods in one program

Tags: java, class, methods, symbols

I'm attempting to have an array (fishWeights) be set to the values that are found using a method. Except that when I try to compile this:

```
public class GoFishEdited {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("\nProject 1, Stage 3\n");

  Habitat h1 = new Habitat();
  Habitat h2 = new Habitat();

  int[] fishWeights = stockUp();     

  System.out.println("Start with some weights:");  
  for (int i : fishWeights) {
     System.out.print(i + " ");
  }

  System.out.println("\n\nMake fish of those weights.\n");

  Fish[] fishGroup = new Fish[fishWeights.length]; // array of Fish

  for (int i=0; i < fishWeights.length; i++) {
     fishGroup[i] = new Fish(fishWeights[i]);  // make fish 
  }

}
}
```

It states that that the symbol stockUp() cannot be found. It is in this file:

```
public class Habitat {

ArrayList stringer = new ArrayList();
public int maxCount=25; 
public int minCount=9; 
public int maxWeight=10; 
public int minWeight=1; 
public int catchProbability=30; //0.3 

public void stockUp(int[] fishArr){

  int numofF = minCount + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxCount - minCount) + 1));

  for(int i = 0; i<numofF; i++){
     fishArr[i] = minWeight + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxWeight - minWeight) + 1));
  }
 }

public Habitat(){

}

public void addFish(Fish f) {
  stringer.add(f);
}

public void removeFish(Fish f){
  stringer.remove(f);
}

public void printFish(){
  System.out.println(stringer);
}
}
```

So stockUp exists, I just can't seem to make getFishEdited to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`stockUp()` is an instance method of the `Habitat` class, so you need to create an instance of `Habitat` in your `GoFishEdited` class's `main` method in order to call it from `GoFishEdited`.  You could call it on either instance of `Habitat` created, `h1` or `h2`  Like this:

```
h1.stockUp();
```

Note that in the code you posted, you need to pass an array of integers as an argument to `stockUp()`, but it looks like in your code you are expecting `stockUp()` to return an `int[]`.  If `stockUp()` is supposed to return an array of integers, then you need to change the method signature to look something like:

```
public int[] stockUp() {

//do whatever you want this method to do

return arrayOfInts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java everything in an object.
So if you want to call method form a class should use

```
Habitat habitat = new Habitat();
habitat.stockUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create an instance of `habitat` using `new Habitat` to call the method in, or you need to make the method `stockUp` static and call it in the `Habitat` class using `Habitat.stockUp`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've created instances of Habitat in h1 and h2, call

```
h1.stockUp(fishArray)
```

Or

```
h2.stockUp(fishArray)
```

depending on what you mean to do. You declared the stockUp() method to accept an int[], so you'll need to pass it one--I called it fishArray, since you seem representing fish. Also, you've declare stockUp() as returning void, so don't expect it to return some value that you can assign to fishWeights. At some point you may find it's a good idea to introduce a Fish class to wrap that concept up better.